# Petit matin / Grand matin

Tags: sens

Both *petit matin* and *grand matin* seem to mean **early morning**. Is this correct?

If they do mean they same thing, how should I say **late morning**?

Merci bien!

** edit

To answer a comment below, the context is from two books I read this year where I noticed that grand and petit seem to mean the same thing...

> Au **petit matin**, des souffles légers parcourent la ville encore
> déserte. A cette heure, qui est entre les morts de la nuit et les
> agonies de la journée, il semble que la peste suspende un instant son
> effort et reprenne son souffle." (from "**La Peste** (French Edition)" by
> Albert Camus)
>
> .. avant l’aurore, il se réveilla tremblant la fièvre et prit le
> chemin de sa demeure, où il arriva de **grand matin**.  (from "**Crime
> et Châtiment** (Pocket classiques t. 17245) (French Edition)" by Fedor
> Dostoievski, Victor Derely)

At first, I assumed that **grand matin** meant in the late morning.

Comment: No, they are not the same thing, but please provide context.

Comment: Yes, they are the same thing but from different centuries. Thanks for providing context.

Answer (score 7):

***Petit matin*** can mean early morning and in that case, it mostly always follows ***au*** or ***le***, the full expression being ***au petit matin***.

A close one is ***de bon matin***.

***(De) grand matin*** used to mean *early morning* in the past, but this form is strongly obsoleted by *petit matin*.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The combination "grand matin" occurs mostly in the expressions "*de grand matin*" and  "*au grand matin*".

> ([expressions-francaises](https://www.expressions-francaises.fr/expressions-d/3214-de-grand-matin.html))
> **De grand matin**
> Signification
>
> De bonne heure (le matin), très tôt (le matin)
> (([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/heure)) **a)** Tôt le matin ou à un moment de la journée en avance sur l'heure fixée ou habituelle. (Ac.).)
>
> Origine de l’expression « de grand matin »
>
> Expression française familière très ancienne qui date du milieu du XVème siècle et qui est de moins en moins utilisée.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/matin))  **De bon matin, au grand matin**. Tôt, aux premières heures du jour.

For "late morning" you can say "*(en/de) fin de matinée*" or "*tard dans la matinée*".

> ([WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/en%20fin%20de%20matin%C3%A9e)) **en fin de matinée** loc adv  (peu avant midi)    late morning, at the end of the morning

> ([Wordhippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the/french-word-for-1ee41ce4b1679055960c368fffa9714772fda464.html)) **late morning** tard dans la matinée

You must be careful in using these expressions. In premodification you can't just translate literally. Modifications of the expressions are necessary so as to preserve acccepted usage.

*For instance*

- They arrived yesterday ***in the* late morning**.→ Ils sont arrivé hier **tard dans la matiné**/**en fin de matinée/ à la fin de la matinée**.
- Those are **late morning** arrivals.→ Ce sont des arrivages ***de* fin de matinée**. *OR* Ce sont des arrivages ***survenus/enregistrés/etc.* tard dans la matinée**.

Comment: *De bonne heure* signifie bien *très tôt* mais pas toujours *le matin*.