# "Lever du soleil" ou "L'aube"

Tags: phrase

What's the differences between "lever du soleil" and "l'aube"? And what are the use cases?

Is it true that "l'aube" is more used in sentences like "untill the sunrise" and the like?
Can these two terms be used interchangeably?

Comment: Not strictly a matter of French language, but perhaps it helps: the terms correspond respectively to *восход солнца* vs. *Рассвет/Заря* in Russian.

Comment: @RogerVadim: You don't need Russian to explain this. In English, *le lever du soleil* is *sunrise* and *l'aube* is *dawn*,  with exactly the same distinction.

Comment: @PeterShor the OP author has a Russian name, so I though it could be helpful. But thanks for pointing out the corresponding terms in English.

Comment: @RogerVadim: you're right — I missed that.

Answer (score 5):

L'**[aube](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aube)** précède l'**[aurore](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aurore)** qui précède le **lever du soleil**.

Les deux premiers mots font partie du vocabulaire soutenu ou littéraire donc sont rares à l'oral où on parlera plutôt de **petit matin** pour indiquer la période où le soleil ne s'est pas encore levé.

---

The **[aube](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aube)** (dawn) precedes the **[aurore](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aurore)** which itself precedes the **lever du soleil** (sunrise).

Both of the first two words belong to the formal / literary vocabulary and are therefore rare in spoken language where we would rather say **petit matin** to talk about the period when the sun has not yet risen.

---

Voir aussi / see also :

- [Aube et aurore, crépuscule et ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/7430/1109)
- [Petit matin / grand matin](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/50674/1109)

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia seems to confirm the hypothesis expressed in the question that *l'aube* refers to the period before the Sun appears above the horizon, whereas *lever de soleil* to the period after that moment:

[Aube](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aube_(temps))

> L'aube (du latin alba, blanche) est le moment de la journée où le ciel commence à s'éclaircir ***avant le lever du Soleil****. Elle est également appelée le « petit matin » dans le langage courant ou le « point du jour » dans des textes plus anciens.

[Lever de soleil](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever_de_soleil)

> Le lever de soleil — ou le lever du Soleil — est la période du jour où, pour un observateur situé à la surface d’un astre du Système solaire — astre en rotation propre sur son axe, planète ou non —, ***le Soleil apparaît progressivement au-dessus de l'horizon du côté est.*** Dans le cas particulier de la Terre, il s'agit ainsi d'un phénomène visible par un observateur situé sur un point donné de la surface du globe terrestre.
>
> ***Le lever du Soleil est précédé de l'aube, pendant laquelle le ciel commence à s'éclairer, quelque temps avant l'apparition du Soleil.***

(emphasis mine)

**Examples**:
As examples of use it is worth citing Victor Hugo's [*Demain, dès l'aube*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demain,_d%C3%A8s_l%27aube%E2%80%A6):

> Demain, dès l'aube, à l'heure où blanchit la campagne,
> Je partirai. Vois-tu, je sais que tu m'attends.
> J'irai par la forêt, j'irai par la montagne.
> Je ne puis demeurer loin de toi plus longtemps.

Hemingway' *The Sun also rises* is rendered in French as [*Le soleil se lève aussi*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_soleil_se_l%C3%A8ve_aussi).